# How to fill-down a formula an entire column by only write it in the first cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How can I fill down any formula like this: `=COUNTIF(A2:D2,"test")` in an entire column by only write it in the first cell `E2`?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps (in E2)

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(if(A2:D="test", row(A2:A)), row(A2:A)))
```

or, depending on your locale

```
=ArrayFormula(countif(if(A2:D="test"; row(A2:A)); row(A2:A)))
```

To hide the zeros in case of empty rows, here is one option:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(countif(if(A2:D="test", row(A2:A)), row(A2:A)) > 0, countif(if(A2:D="test", row(A2:A)), row(A2:A)),))
```

Comment: Hi @JPV, thank you so much for your answer, your formula is working well, but now I want to can keep the other cells in `E` column empty and hide the `0` until I enter the data https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoLNm.png , can you help me with this?